# dplyr: Divide all values by mean of first subgroup

Tags: r

**edit: The question has been answered by user arg0naut. Thank you!**

I have many observations that are organized in groups (named 2-4) and subgroups (named 1-6). I would like to divide every single observation in a group by the mean value of its subgroup 1 (in order to standardize every data point in the group to the mean value of its subgroup 1). Also, some observations are NA.

This is the code I try to tweak, so far it divides every Observation by the overall mean:

```
data %>%
group_by(Group) %>%
mutate("New Variable" = Observation / mean(Observation, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I do not know how to indicate that I don't want the overall mean, but the mean value of subgroup 1 of every group. I've been trying for hours, but keep failing.

I attached a picture that may help you to understand what I mean.

Thank you for your consideration!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EYPK.png)

Comment: `mean(Observation[Subgroup == 1], na.rm = TRUE)` could help

Comment: Wow, yes, it did! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not to `group_by(Group, subgroup)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is to group by ***subgroup*** instead of ***group***.
Here is an example :

```
data <-
  data.frame(
    "Group" =  rep(2, 15),
    "Subgroup" = rep (1:2, c(10, 5)),
    "Observation" = c(rnorm(14), NA)
  )
data %>%
  group_by(Subgroup) %>%
  mutate("New variable" = Observation / mean(Observation, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This will divide each subgroup by its own mean (subgroup 1 / mean(subgroup 1), subgroup 2 / mean(subgroup 2), ...). OP wants to divide each subgroup by subgroup 1's mean: subgroup 1 / mean(subgroup 1), subgroup 2 / mean(subgroup **1**), ... (within the same group)

Comment: Question still needs an answer... if you group by `Group` and use arg0naut's comment on the question as a hint you can probably get there